# Image taken with ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE - first decodeStream call fails, others OK

Tags: android

I'm using `ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE` with a predetermined target Uri pretty much as suggested in the documentation. However, when I try to decode the image immediately after my activity gets it, `decodeStream()` fails. If I try it again a few seconds later, it works fine. I suppose the file is being written asynchronously in the background. How can I find out when it's available for use?

Here are the key parts of my code:

Determining the target file name:

```
String filename = String.format("pic%d.jpg", new Date().getTime());
File file = new File(context.getExternalFilesDir(Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES), filename);

try {
    file.createNewFile();
} catch (IOException e) {
    file = new File(context.getFilesDir(), filename);
}
targetUri = Uri.fromFile(photoFile);
```

Taking the picture:

```
Intent takePictureIntent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
takePictureIntent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, targetUri);
fragment.startActivityForResult(takePictureIntent, RESULT_TAKE_PICTURE);
```

In `onActivityResult()`:

```
if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
    if (data != null) {
        // Note that data.getData() is null here.
        InputStream is = getContentResolver().openInputStream(targetUri);
        if (is != null) {
            Bitmap bm = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(is);
```

`decodeStream` returns null. If I make the same call again a few seconds later, it succeeds. Is there anything that tells me when the file is available?

**UPDATE**: Following greenapps' suggestion, I'm doing a `decodeStream` call with `inJustDecodeBounds` first to get the dimensions to see if it's a memory issue. Turns out this first bounds-only decode pass fails, but now the actual decodeStream call that immediately follows succeeds! If I then do both again, they both succeed!

So it seems like the first call to `decodeStream` always fails, and all the others after that are good, even if they happen immediately afterwards (=within the same method). So it's probably not a problem with an asynchronous write. But something else. But what?

Comment: targetUri and uri?

Comment: How did you set up targetUri? From a file system path? Then use decodeFile on the original path.

Comment: `I suppose the file is being written asynchronously in the background`. I think decodeStream returns null because of lack of memory. Some time later the gc has recovered enough. Try with just decode bounds.

Comment: @greenapps Apologies, stupid oversight. I added the code that creates the filename. Tries to get one in the pictures directory, falls back to the app-private directory if that's not possible. targetUri and uri are identical, I had accidentally used two different names when I "normalized" all the names as I copied them into this question.

Comment: @greenapps I'm not so sure on the memory theory though. Bitmaps are expensive, but this is on a Nexus 6P with 3GB RAM, and IIRC decodeStream throws an exception if it runs out of memory. If gc could have recovered memory, it probably would have done so. This is also too repeatable to be a problem like that.

Comment: @greenapps Okay, I tried decode only as you suggested, and it's interesting - the bounds-only decode pass fails, but the one immediately after that to load the full image succeeds! So it seems like the first decode pass always fails, all subsequent calls are good. Huh.

Comment: `decodeStream throws an exception if it runs out of memory`. No. It returns null. But anyhow you found a work around.

Comment: @EboMike whats the OS with the problem?

Comment: @Elenasys Android N. I can't comment on which version exactly :) So it may actually be a bug in the OS, I'll look into that further and see if I have some other devices to test this on. I'll still assume for now that there is something I can do on my side to avoid this problem.

Answer (score 2):

```
if (requestCode == Utility.GALLERY_PICTURE) {

        Uri selectedImageUri = null;
        try {
            selectedImageUri = data.getData();
            if (mImgProfilePic != null) {
                // mImgProfilePic.setImageURI(selectedImageUri);
                mImgProfilePic.setImageBitmap(decodeUri(getActivity(),
                        selectedImageUri, 60));
                // decodeUri

            }
        } catch (Exception e) {

        }
        // //////////////
        try {
            // Bundle extras = data.getExtras();
            // // get the cropped bitmap
            // Bitmap thePic = extras.getParcelable("data");
            // mImgProfilePic.setImageBitmap(thePic);

            final Uri tempUri = selectedImageUri;
            Log.d("check", "uri " + tempUri);
            // http://dev1.brainpulse.org/quickmanhelp/webservice/api.php?act=companylogo
            upLoadServerUri = "http://dev1.brainpulse.org/quickmanhelp/webservice/api.php?act=employee_profile_pic&image=";
            upLoadServerUri = Utility.EMPLOYEE_PROFILE_PIC_URL
                    + "&employee_id=" + empId;
            dialog = ProgressDialog.show(getActivity(), "",
                    "Uploading file...", true);

            new Thread(new Runnable() {
                public void run() {
                    getActivity().runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                        public void run() {
                            // messageText.setText("uploading started.....");
                        }
                    });
                    uploadFilePath = getRealPathFromURI(tempUri);
                    uploadFile(uploadFilePath + "");
                    // uploadFile(tempUri+"");
                }
            }).start();

        } catch (Exception e) {

        }

        // ///////

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public static void updateFile(File file ,Context context) {
        MediaScannerConnection.scanFile(context,
                new String[]{file.getAbsolutePath()}, null,
                new MediaScannerConnection.OnScanCompletedListener() {
                    public void onScanCompleted(String path, Uri uri) {
                    }
                }
        );
    }
```

I think you can use this to update before you openInputStream.

Answer (score 0):

From the snippet you shared I thiiink problem is that you are setting Image file to File variable **file**

```
 File file = new File(context.getExternalFilesDir(Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES), filename);
```

But you are setting image Uri from File **photoFile** which is probably null

```
targetUri = Uri.fromFile(photoFile);
```

So basically you need to replace `targetUri = Uri.fromFile(photoFile);` with `targetUri = Uri.fromFile(file);`

Or even better **`data.getData()`** will return Image URi directlty like this

```
InputStream is = null;
        try {
            is = getContentResolver().openInputStream(data.getData());
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        if (is != null) {
            Bitmap bm = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(is);

            ((ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView1)).setImageBitmap(bm);
        }
```

You still need to decode bitmap to avoid OOM exception you can use `Glide` to load image using image URI.

Complete Class Tested on Xpria C

```
    package com.example.test;

    import java.io.File;
    import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
    import java.io.IOException;
    import java.io.InputStream;
    import java.util.Date;

    import android.app.Activity;
    import android.content.Intent;
    import android.graphics.Bitmap;
    import android.graphics.BitmapFactory;
    import android.net.Uri;
    import android.os.Bundle;
    import android.os.Environment;
    import android.provider.MediaStore;
    import android.view.View;
    import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
    import android.widget.ImageView;

    public class TestActivity extends Activity {

        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_test);

            findViewById(R.id.take_picture).setOnClickListener(
                    new OnClickListener() {

                        @Override
                        public void onClick(View v) {
                            dispatchTakePictureIntent();
                        }
                    });
        }

        static final int REQUEST_TAKE_PHOTO = 1;

        private void dispatchTakePictureIntent() {
            Intent takePictureIntent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
            // Ensure that there's a camera activity to handle the intent
            if (takePictureIntent.resolveActivity(getPackageManager()) != null) {
                // Create the File where the photo should go
                File photoFile = null;
                try {
                    photoFile = createImageFile();
                } catch (IOException ex) {
                    // Error occurred while creating the File
                }
                // Continue only if the File was successfully created
                if (photoFile != null) {
                    takePictureIntent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT,
                            Uri.fromFile(photoFile));
                    startActivityForResult(takePictureIntent, REQUEST_TAKE_PHOTO);
                }
            }
        }

        protected static final int RESULT_TAKE_PICTURE = 100;

        private File createImageFile() throws IOException {
            // Create an image file name
            String filename = String.format("pic%d.jpg", new Date().getTime());
            File file = new File(
                    getExternalFilesDir(Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES), filename);

            try {
                file.createNewFile();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                file = new File(getFilesDir(), filename);
            }

            return file;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
            if (requestCode == REQUEST_TAKE_PHOTO && resultCode == RESULT_OK) {

                InputStream is = null;
                try {
                    is = getContentResolver().openInputStream(data.getData());
                } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                if (is != null) {
                    Bitmap bm = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(is);

                    ((ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView1)).setImageBitmap(bm);
                }
            }


}
}
```